# How add notify url to REST API paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I created simple payment in paypal

```
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $item1 = new Item();
    $item1->setName('some name')
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setSku("my id product") 
        ->setPrice(11);

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1));

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal(11);

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $baseUrl = "https://my_site_address.com";
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment/?success=true")
        ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment/?success=false");


    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));


   $request = clone $payment;

    try {
        $payment->create($apiContext);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        print_r($ex);
        exit(1);
    }

    $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
    print_r($approvalUrl);
```

After execute this code everything is alright, I am redirected to Paypal sandbox and after log in i can make a pay. But I don't know how, where i can set my notify_url?

Anyone can help ?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ look at the notifications section

Comment: I did, but i still don't get it. I can't find simple example. How can i set my return address ? why is so hard ?

Comment: return or notify? because they are not the same thing

Comment: i mean notify. When someone mada payment i expect paypal send me notify to me and i will check payment as OK or NOT.

Comment: notification section web_hooks is what you want https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for notify url can't be used in REST API calls. If you want to set up the IPN url, you have to set it within your Paypal account:
Here is the steps:
1. Login paypal account
2. Click profile and under Selling preferences, choose Instant Payment Notification preferences 
3. Click Choose IPN setting
4. Type the URL that you receive IPN message and choose Enabled

Answer (score 3):

the direct and short answer to your question is yes you can set a "`notifyUrl`" via REST API:

```
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription(" ...... ")
            ->setNotifyUrl("your notifyUrl here")
            ->setInvoiceNumber($invoiceNo);
```

**BUT** this is **not** the correct way receiving REST Notifications. Use "Webhooks" instead (though Webhooks using PHP is soo hacky, but at the end you find a solution. if you need more details on how to do it, just comment this answer).

**Back to `NotofyUrl`:**
for testing i was able to receive notifications via notifyUrl, **BUT** after implementing a webhook, PayPal still sending notifications to my old already removed NotifyUrl for every new Payment. i deleted it from the code, i deactivated IPN in my PayPal account. I tried many things, but PayPal still sending IPNs for every Payment. Now i receive 2 Notofications, one via NofityUrl and the second via WebhookEvent Listener. no idea whats going wrong here. So i wouldn't recommend the usage of notifyUrl, instead just implement a webhookEvent listener.

Comment: do you receive a webhook on the monthly recurring billing?